How to Calculate the Correct Orientation (rx, ry, rz) When Rotating a Pose Around an Axis in 3D Space in Python
I created a function to compute the rotated pose around a given rotation axis. Here is my code:
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation


def rotate_pose(pose: list, axis: list, rotation_center: list, angle: float):
    """
    :param pose: the target pose need to be rotated
    :param axis: the rotation axis direction vector
    :param rotation_center: the rotation axis location
    :param angle: the rotation angle
    :return:
    the rotated pose
    """
    rotation_center = np.array(rotation_center)
    axis = np.array(axis)
    axis = axis / np.linalg.norm(axis)
    
    # move pose location to the rotation center
    translation_matrix = np.eye(4)
    translation_matrix[:3, 3] = -rotation_center
    centered = np.dot(np.hstack((pose[:3], np.ones(1))), translation_matrix.T)[:3]

    # compute the rotation matrix
    rotation_matrix = Rotation.from_rotvec(np.pi * axis).as_matrix()
    new_pose_centered = np.dot(centered, rotation_matrix.T)

    # move pose back to the original location
    translation_matrix_inv = np.eye(4)
    translation_matrix_inv[:3, 3] = rotation_center
    new_location = np.dot(np.hstack((new_pose_centered, np.ones(1))), translation_matrix_inv.T)[:3]

    # compute quaternion and orientation
    rotation_quaternion = Rotation.from_rotvec(np.pi * axis).as_quat()
    new_orientation = Rotation.from_quat(rotation_quaternion).apply(pose[3:])

    # combine the new location and new orientation
    new_pose = np.hstack((new_location, new_orientation))

    return new_pose

I also created some test cases to check my function:
CASE 1
Input:
pose = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0]
axis = [0,0,1]
rotation_center = [1, 1, 1]
angle = np.pi

Output:
array([ 2.,  2.,  0., -1., -1.,  0.])

CASE 2
Input:
pose = [10, 0, 3, np.pi / 2, np.pi, 0]
axis = [0,0,1]
rotation_center = [0, 1, 1]
angle = np.pi / 2

Output:
array([-10.        ,   2.        ,   3.        ,  -1.57079633,
        -3.14159265,   0.        ])


I set the Z-axis as the rotation axis ([0, 0, 1]) to test my function, and I found that the output location is correct, but the orientation is not. According to the definition, "rz" typically represents the rotation angle around the Z-axis. So, when I rotate the target pose with the Z-axis, the new orientation should be [old_rx, old_ry, old_rz + rotation_angle]. However, my function returns a different result, and I don't know how the wrong answer happened.
